# Function declared inside and outside of a component behaves differently in a Functional Component but works same in Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, class, material-ui

I am using MaterialUi Snackbar with `Slide` transition.
**Expected Behaviour**: Snackbar should slide in the provided direction and retreat on close.

This code is working.
Here's the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Snackbar from "@mui/material/Snackbar";
import Slide from "@mui/material/Slide";
import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";

const Transition = (newprops) => {
  console.log("CustomMUISnackBar Transition props: ", newprops);
  return <Slide {...newprops} direction="up" />;
};

function CustomMUISnackBar(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(props.open);
  }, [props.open]);

  return (
    <Snackbar
      autoHideDuration={1000}
      TransitionComponent={Transition}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "center" }}
      open={open}
      onClose={() => {
        setOpen(false);
        props.onClose();
      }}
      key="Slide"
    >
      <Alert
        onClose={() => {
          setOpen(false);
          props.onClose();
        }}
        severity="success"
        sx={{ width: "100%" }}
      >
        <i style={{ color: "blue" }}>{props.updatedUserName}</i>'s details
        updated!
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  );
}

export default CustomMUISnackBar;
```

But if I place `Transition` function inside the functional component's body then only the first part of the `Slide` works as in it shows the snackbar opening with sliding but disappears without sliding.

```
function CustomMUISnackBar(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const Transition = (newprops) => {
    console.log("CustomMUISnackBar Transition props: ", newprops);
    return <Slide {...newprops} direction="up" />;
  };

  return ();
}

export default CustomMUISnackBar;
```

It only happens when I use the Snackbar in a separate Component.js and then use it somewhere. If I use it directly it works whether I place the `Transition` function inside the component or outside it.
Below code works for both buttons:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Snackbar from "@mui/material/Snackbar";
import Slide from "@mui/material/Slide";
import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";

const OutsideTransition = (tprops) => {
  console.log("Outside Transition props: ", tprops);
  return <Slide {...tprops} direction="up" />;
};

function CustomMUISnackBar(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    open: false,
    transition: undefined
  });
  const InsideTransition = (tprops) => {
    console.log("Outside Transition props: ", tprops);
    return <Slide {...tprops} direction="up" />;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Snackbar
        autoHideDuration={1000}
        TransitionComponent={state.transition}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "center" }}
        open={state.open}
        onClose={() => setState({ ...state, open: false })}
        key={state.transition?.name}
      >
        <Alert
          onClose={() => setState({ ...state, open: false })}
          severity="success"
        >
          <i style={{ color: "blue" }}>"Update Success!"</i>'s details updated!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
      <button
        onClick={() => setState({ open: true, transition: OutsideTransition })}
      >
        SanckBar OutsideTransition
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => setState({ open: true, transition: InsideTransition })}
      >
        SanckBar InsideTransition
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default CustomMUISnackBar;
```

If I use class Component in a separate component.js file, then also it works as expected.

This code works:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Snackbar from "@mui/material/Snackbar";
import Slide from "@mui/material/Slide";
import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";

const Transition = (newprops) => {
  console.log("CustomMUISnackBar Transition props: ", newprops);
  return <Slide {...newprops} direction="up" />;
};

class CustomMUISnackBarClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { open: props.open };
  }
  TransitionMethod = (newprops) => {
    console.log("CustomMUISnackBar Transition props: ", newprops);
    return <Slide {...newprops} direction="up" />;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Snackbar
        autoHideDuration={1000}
        TransitionComponent={this.TransitionMethod}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "center" }}
        open={this.state.open}
        onClose={() => {
          this.setState({ open: false });
          this.props.onClose();
        }}
        key="Slide"
      >
        <Alert
          onClose={() => {
            this.setState({ open: false });
            this.props.onClose();
          }}
          severity="success"
          sx={{ width: "100%" }}
        >
          <i style={{ color: "blue" }}>{this.props.updatedUserName}</i>'s
          details updated!
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomMUISnackBarClass;
```

Above code works even if `TransitionComponent={this.TransitionMethod}` is replaced with `TransitionComponent={Transition}`.

So, my question is how the functionality is getting differed in functional and class component. What is changing if a function is declared inside a functional component or outside as compared to behaviour when a functional component is defined in a `component.js` file?

Here's the code at codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/transitionsnackbar-eillp. Wait for few seconds before clicking on other buttons.